# TSQL to append data in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column named `ADDRESS` that has, as one guessed, addresses in it in the format of `100 NE 26th ST`. So basically its the street address. What I want to do is add `BLK` after the numerical so the end result is `100 BLK NE 26th ST`. Now I ran a simple script that changed `00` to `00 BLK`, however when there was a street name of say `100th ST`, it blew it up.

So basically is there a way to add `BLK` right after the house number and before the street name??

Comment: what if it has `P.O Box`?

Comment: That'sa very good point. Didnt think of that.. or no address at all which many dont have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Address TABLE(Address1 VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @Address VALUES
('100 NE 26th ST.'),
('100th NE 26th ST.'),
('P.O. Box 133'),
(''),
(NULL)

SELECT CASE WHEN Address1 LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN 
    STUFF(Address1,CHARINDEX(' ',Address1),1,' BLK ')
    ELSE Address1 END
FROM @Address
```

Gordon is right about stuff.. but you might want to check for po box or blanks.. or null

**Edit**

Based on your comments.. to update your People table you would simply do.

```
UPDATE People
SET Address1 = CASE WHEN Address1 LIKE '[0-9]%' 
                    THEN STUFF(Address1,CHARINDEX(' ',Address1),1,' BLK ')
                    ELSE Address1 END
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you want to add "BLK" where the first space is.  You can accomplish this with:

```
select stuff(address, charindex(' ', address), 1, ' BLK ')
```

That logic works for the situations you describe in the question, but it may not fully generalize to what you really need -- depending on other eccentricities in the addresses.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, there seems to be a syntax error right after "address," 

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.

when I ran this : select top 1000 (address, charindex(' ', address), 1, ' BLK ')

also what if the address field is blank? Will it ignor? Hopefully :-)

Comment: @Sal looks like you forgot the word `stuff` in your query.. `select top 1000 stuff(address, charindex(' ', address), 1, ' BLK ')`

Comment: @jamied77 I'm still getting an error. I'm trying an update as well not so much a select but I think its due to no table name being included. The table name is PEOPLE and the actualy column name is address1. So based on that, what do you suggest?